# Como resolver esse problema do Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot

Estou aprendendo a usar o `Spring Boot`, seguindo/adaptando [esse tutorial da página oficial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/), mas sempre quando tento rodar, aparecem essas exceções e erros:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-09-30 14:39:17.508 ERROR 112 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter]: Factory method 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcConversionService' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService]: Factory method 'mvcConversionService' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.cadastroSimples.models.User
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:590) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1247) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1096) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:535) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:780) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:333) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1277) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1265) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at com.cadastroSimples.cadastroSimples.CadastroSimplesApplication.main(CadastroSimplesApplication.java:10) [main/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter]: Factory method 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcConversionService' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService]: Factory method 'mvcConversionService' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.cadastroSimples.models.User
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcConversionService' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService]: Factory method 'mvcConversionService' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.cadastroSimples.models.User
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:590) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1247) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1096) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:535) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.resolveBeanReference(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:396) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:368) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3b09ef61.mvcConversionService(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.getConfigurableWebBindingInitializer(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:602) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.getConfigurableWebBindingInitializer(WebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:524) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.requestMappingHandlerAdapter(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:564) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.requestMappingHandlerAdapter(WebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:467) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3b09ef61.CGLIB$requestMappingHandlerAdapter$6(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3b09ef61$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$5a08a2d2.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:365) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3b09ef61.requestMappingHandlerAdapter(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService]: Factory method 'mvcConversionService' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.cadastroSimples.models.User
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    ... 49 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.cadastroSimples.models.User
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1699) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1095) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories.cacheRepositoryFactory(Repositories.java:97) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories.populateRepositoryFactoryInformation(Repositories.java:90) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories.<init>(Repositories.java:83) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.support.DomainClassConverter.setApplicationContext(DomainClassConverter.java:109) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.web.config.SpringDataWebConfiguration.addFormatters(SpringDataWebConfiguration.java:131) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerComposite.addFormatters(WebMvcConfigurerComposite.java:81) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.addFormatters(DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.java:78) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.mvcConversionService(WebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:495) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3b09ef61.CGLIB$mvcConversionService$9(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3b09ef61$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$5a08a2d2.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:365) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3b09ef61.mvcConversionService(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    ... 50 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.cadastroSimples.models.User
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:473) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:74) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:66) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:180) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:118) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:101) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:304) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$4(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:290) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:141) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:63) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:293) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:102) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1695) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    ... 75 common frames omitted
```

Alguém pode me ajudar a entender isso para resolver esse problema? Seguem os meu códigos:

Como gerenciador de dependência estou usando o `Gradle`.

Arquivo `build.gradlew`:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.5.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.cadastroSimples'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf')
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    runtimeOnly('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
    runtimeOnly('mysql:mysql-connector-java')
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

Minha estrutura de pastas está assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Arquivo `CadastroSimplesApplication.java`

```
package com.cadastroSimples.cadastroSimples;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class CadastroSimplesApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CadastroSimplesApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Arquivo `UserRepository.java`:

```
package com.cadastroSimples.cadastroSimples;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import com.cadastroSimples.models.User;

public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Integer> {

}
```

Arquivo `IndexController.java`

```
package com.cadastroSimples.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class IndexController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

Arquivo `MainController.java`:

package com.cadastroSimples.controllers;

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import com.cadastroSimples.cadastroSimples.UserRepository;
import com.cadastroSimples.models.User;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(path="/demo")
public class MainCotroller {
    @Autowired
    public UserRepository userRepository;

    @GetMapping(path="/add")
    public @ResponseBody String addNewUser(@RequestParam String name, @RequestParam String email) {
        User n = new User();
        n.setName(name);
        n.setEmail(email);
        userRepository.save(n);
        return "Saved";
    }

    @GetMapping(path="/all")
    public @ResponseBody Iterable<User> getAllUsers(){
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

Arquivo `User.java`:

```
package com.cadastroSimples.models;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String email;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

Arquivo `application.properties`:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cadastro_simples?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=meuusuario
spring.datasource.password=minhasenha
```

Comment: Experimente colocar o arquivo `CadastroSimplesApplication.java` em um pacote um nível acima dos demais. Por exemplo: coloque-o no pacote `com.cadastroSimples`.

Comment: @StatelessDev muito obrigada por responder! :-) Sua sugestão, me ajudou a resolveu parte do problema. Agora aparecem problemas com a conexão com o MySQL. Infelizmente, as exceções não cabem no corpo da resposta, mas coloquei [nesse link para que possa ser lida](https://gist.github.com/vanribeiro/a6cadf044bcdd4293c166c03ef6c40aa).

Comment: O erro: Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect. Verifica se o seu banco está acessível de fato em localhost:3306.

Comment: @GiulianaBezerra muito obrigada por responder! :-) Algo estranho aconteceu. Estava conseguindo logar normalmente no MySQL. Hoje, fui logar no `MySQL Command Line Cliente` ele fecha sozinho e se tento logar no CMD recebo esse `ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)`.

Comment: @VanRibeiro Já que o problema motivador desta questão foi resolvido, vou criar uma resposta e você, por gentileza, marque-a como correta para ajudar outros usuários. Sugiro que, quanto ao problema de conexão, você abra outra pergunta, colando na própria pergunta a stack de erro.

Comment: @GiulianaBezerra e StatelessDev resolvido! :-) Obrigada pela ajuda! O problema com o MySQL foi resolvido da seguinte forma: por algum motivo, que eu não sei explicar, o Serviço do Windows desabilitou a execução do serviço do MySQL. Ajustei isso e agora está tudo funcionando! :-)

Comment: @StatelessDev, ok! Sem problemas! E muito obrigada pela ajuda! ^_^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O Spring Boot possui o recurso de autoscan, que escaneia classes em busca de beans para serem gerenciados por ele. O comportamento padrão é escanear pacotes abaixo daquele em que a classe com o método `main` está localizada (você pode indicar um local específico para escaneamento, mas a princípio isso não lhe interessa).

Desta maneira, o ideal, sempre, é que o pacote de maior nível no seu projeto contenha o arquivo que possui essa classe que inicializa o projeto, no seu caso, a classe `CadastroSimplesApplication.java`, que pode ser colocada no pacote `com.cadastroSimples`. Desta forma, todas as demais classes e pacotes estarão abaixo, e o autoscan do Spring vai localizá-las.